# Неправильно работают кнопки внутри ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

У меня есть `ListView`, в каждом элементе которого есть 2 кнопки.
Я, естественно, использую свой адаптер для отображения `ListView`.
В функции `getView`, которая формирует вью для конкретной строки списка я выставляю `OnClick` хендлеры для этих кнопок.

Проблема в том, что кнопки начинают реагировать на клики только после второй перерисовки. То есть, что бы нажать на кнопку, которая находится в первой строке списка, мне нужно опустить список вниз так, что бы первая строка ушла за пределы экрана, и перерисовалась.

Вопрос: как вызвать принудительную перерисовку (или что там вызывается перед отрисовкой строки),  или как выставить онклик обработчики так, что бы они работали сразу?

Comment: Кинь лучше код

Comment: В общем, весь нэт облазил, ответа так и не нашел. похожей ситуации видимо не было ни у кого...

Пришлось очень сильно по извращаться, наделать кучу "граблей", и кучу непонятного мусора, в общем набыдлокодить... Но самое удивительное, что все таки оно заработало. Я даже не пытаюсь теперь понять как... боюсь поламать...

Всем спасибо!

Comment: > Но самое удивительное, что все-таки оно заработало. Я даже не пытаюсь теперь понять, как.

Это непрофессиональный подход. :)

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что выставление хэндлеров в `getView()` - это плохая идея. Я бы сделал по другому: сначала бы сформировал массив вьюшек, выставил бы каждому из них хэндлеры, потом при рисовании `ListView` уже брал вьюшки из массива и возвращал через `getView()`.

Comment: дело в том, что я точно так и делаю, просто решил упростить вопрос до более общей ситуации.
но все равно кнопки начинают реагировать на клики только после пролистывания списка вверх-вниз...

Comment: Попробуйте добавить уникальный `id` каждой вьюшке, например через статический `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` - возможно вы клики не различаете по айдишкам

Comment: Лучше по.setTag()

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, поможет ли, но попробуйте вызвать прорисовку списка вручную: `listview.invalidate()`. Если конечно они ведут себя так из-за прорисовки, как Вы говорите.

Answer (score 1):

У меня недавно тоже стояла такая задача (элементы у меня были все одного вида). Как я поступил: набросал шаблон одного элемента `ListView` в `xml` (две кнопки, три текстовых поля и прогресс бар). Затем в `xml` для кнопок назначил обработчики нажатия событий:

```
...
  android:OnClick = ""
 ...
```

и уже когда формировал адаптер, я добавил свой `ViewBinder` через `.setViewBinder` у адаптера. В этом `ViewBinder'e` я каждой кнопке присваивал тег, который зависел от номера элемента в списке `ListView`, и уже в обработчике я смотрел у `View` тег и выполнял свои действия. Может это тебе поможет. У меня не возникло никаких проблем с нажатием на кнопки, все запустилось с первого раза.

Если не понятно будет, могу привести пример кода.